# How Do I Write In A Common File From Separate Projects?

Tags: c#

How can I write in a common file from separate projects?
I created TextWriter in Initializing each project, then write logs in whole of projects.

```
_Writer = TextWriter.Synchronized(new StreamWriter(path));
```

When it needs to write log, I call:

```
_Writer.WriteLine(line);
_Writer.Flush();
```

But when first project runs, second one can't create `TextWriter` then it(second project) doesn't write any thing in common log file.

How do I create TextWriter object in **share writing** mode for file in common path ?

Comment: One way to do this (though you could still run into file locking problems) is to wrap the `TextWriter` (or whatever) in a using block - that will close the file as soon as the operation is finished.  Put that code in a common library used by your other components.  You may still get occasional locks due to another process having the file however.

Comment: Why aren't you using a dedicated logging library like log4net or NLog?

Comment: Whilst you *can* arrange to open a file for writing from multiple programs, they will *not* have a shared view of where the end of the file is at any particular moment in time and so, absent some high level coordination, they'll end up trashing each others logs. Better to maintain separate logs and only merge them when you *need* a unified view of them.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is logging you can use [**Enterprise Library Logging**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.logging.aspx) which will handle everything for you. Create the logger as a separate library and use them in which ever projects you want.